# How to build a graph using random distance matrix?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to generate **random transportation graphs** in R with n vertices.

The graphs should be **bipartite and connected** ( there is usually a link / way between 2 vertices , not usually a direct one ) without " Loops".

In addition , the edges valuation should be **random & strictly positive** .

I tried doing the following :

```
n=6  # number of vertices 
F <- erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m=0.5, directed=FALSE)
m=ecount(F)
min = 1    # 1 km
max = 50   # 50 km 
F <- set.edge.attribute(F, name="distance", value=runif(m , min , max))
plot(F, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
distances(F)
```

The problem is that i failed to get the wanted distances in the graph distance matrix :

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    2    1    1    2    1
[2,]    2    0    2    1    1    1
[3,]    1    2    0    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    0    2    1
[5,]    2    1    1    2    0    1
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
```

Normally , i should get uniform random values between 1 and 50 .

Also i'm not sure if the graph will not contain a loop if i execute another occurence of this code in future.

I guess my questions are clear !
Thank you if you could help !

Comment: Could someone help ?

Comment: it might help if you clarify a few things. Do you want, for example, 50km to be a *property* of an edge between two vertices--so that A--B are 50km apart? Because with a graph of size 6 there is no way to get a distance a 50. Distance is the number of edges separating two vertices: A--B is 1, A--C--B is two, etc.

Comment: @paqmo  . I mean by the distance : The cost or the maximum flow that could go within an edge ( an edge is defined by two adjacent vertices )

Comment: The range of the flow within an edge should be between 1km and 50 km , the values of the flows are drawn by random ( uniform law ) .

Comment: add the edge attribute to `distances()`--`distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance)`?

Comment: @paqmo , yes it works . How can i get the shortest paths matrix with the corresponding flows ( for example : if i know the minimum path between two selected vertices , how could i get the corresponding flow / weight ) .

Comment: `distances()` gives the shortest paths between vertices, so I'm not sure what you want differently here. If you want specific vertices, add the `v=` and `to=` arguments: `distances(F, v = 1, to = 6, weights = E(F)$distance)`

Comment: @paqmo , I understand . I want to get edges values ( the capacity of an edge ) , it's my last question ? Thank you a lot for your valuable help !

Comment: all edge values: `E(F)$distance` for specific edge values: `E(F)[1 %—% 2]$distance`

Comment: @paqmo , thank you a lot for your precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution :

```
n=6  # number of vertices 
F <- erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m=0.5, directed=FALSE) # We create the graph F 
m=ecount(F)  # number of edges we obtained using erdos.renyi.game() 
min = 1    # 1 km    # min and max values for the edges flows 
max = 50   # 50 km 
F <- set.edge.attribute(F, name="distance", value=runif(m , min , max)) # The flows are drawn in random 
plot(F, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold) # we plot the graph F
distances(F)    # matrix of lentghs of the shortest paths between i & j
distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance) # matrix of flows of the shortest paths 
distances(F, v = 1, to = 6, weights = E(F)$distance) # same if we want a specific minimum path between two vertices ( ex : 1--->6 ) 
get.all.shortest.paths(F, 1, to = V(F)) # all shortest paths list 
graph.maxflow(F, 1, 6) # the maximum possible flow of any route between 1--->6
```

Comment: last line gives error: `Error in max_flow(F, v = 1, to = 6, capacity = NULL) :   unused arguments (v = 1, to = 6)`. This is interesting stuff. Might be helpful to someone in the future if you fix that last line.